# App image uploader replaces previously-uploaded image Markdown with most recently-uploaded image URL

Tags: bug, status-completed, android-app, uploader

When using the Stack Exchange App for Android, I encountered a problem when uploading multiple images to the same post.

After uploading a single image, the image Markdown is inserted normally, e.g.:

```
![enter image description here][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cbh1m.jpg
```

As I upload more images, the list of URLs at the bottom of the post should be appended to. After uploading the above in a new post, I tap to place the cursor at the end of the first line, enter a newline and the toolbar reappears. I then upload a second image with this result:

```
![enter image description here][1]
![enter image description here][2]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cbh1m.jpg
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/V5nXV.jpg
```

Now I edit the image descriptions, to make sure I can keep track of all my images, place the cursor at the end of the second line and enter a newline. The edit box contains:

```
![a black circle of utter blackness][1]
![the best planet earth clip art ever][2]



  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cbh1m.jpg
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/V5nXV.jpg
```

I then upload a third image. What's interesting is that *as the screen reloads*, for an instant I see `the best planet earth clip art ever` replaced by more image markup, so the second line is this:

```
![![enter image description here][2]][2]
```

But only for a moment. Then the screen updates, and the edit window is left in this state:

```
![the best planet earth clip art ever][2]
![the best planet earth clip art ever][2]
![enter image description here][3]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cbh1m.jpg
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/V5nXV.jpg
  [3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Ra5w.jpg
```

I correct the first line and insert a line break after the third line in preparation to upload the first image again (I really love blackness). Before uploading, the edit window looks like this:

```
![a black circle of utter blackness][1]
![the best planet earth clip art ever][2]
![a fast computer][3]



  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cbh1m.jpg
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/V5nXV.jpg
  [3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Ra5w.jpg
```

After uploading:

```
![a fast computer][3]
![the best planet earth clip art ever][2]
![a fast computer][3]
![enter image description here][4]



  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cbh1m.jpg
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/V5nXV.jpg
  [3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Ra5w.jpg
  [4]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ILUCC.jpg
```

Now, instead of adding a newline, I position my cursor at the end of the third line. The toolbar isn't visible so I insert a space and then delete it. I upload another copy of the *third* image from this position *adjacent* to other image markdown, and now the result is:

```
![a fast computer][3]
![the best planet earth clip art ever][2]
![a fast computer][3]![enter image description here][4]
![enter image description here][4]



  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Ra5w.jpg
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/V5nXV.jpg
  [3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Ra5w.jpg
  [4]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jG0fk.jpg
  [5]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ILUCC.jpg
```

Notice:

- The new image, the fifth I have uploaded, goes in as image `[4]`. Not a problem, so far, but:
- The previous image description is still linked to image `[4]`, now a different URL; and
- The first URL in the list has been overwritten by the URL of the third image, which happens to be immediately adjacent on the line where I inserted the most recently-uploaded image.

Reproduced at the time of this question revision, with the following specs:

- Device: Moto G 2013
- OS version: 4.4.4
- App version: 1.0.57

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will be fixed in 1.0.84.

The problem and solution are described in [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/277077/235711).